# Can we find the number of rows and columns inside every table in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

There is a difference in count of rows and columns in QA env and Prod env. So, I wanted to know is there any query in SQL(SQL server management studio I am using) through which I can know the number of rows and columns inside every table in database.

I do the same to check the no of rows and col in parquet file in Python

```
l=[]
m=[]
l_parquet=[]
m_parquet=[]
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/dbfs/mnt/sgi/report/"):
  for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".parquet")]:
        path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        l.append(path)
        df_parquet=pd.read_parquet(path)
        l_parquet.append(df_parquet.shape[0])
        m_parquet.append(df_parquet.shape[1])
weatther={'path':l, 'count_of_rows':l_parquet, 'count_of_col':m_parquet}
df=pd.DataFrame(weatther)
df.to_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/QA_count_2.csv')
```

Same I want to do in SQL

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag since your question is specific to Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example query using SQL Server [object catalog views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/object-catalog-views-transact-sql) to return the table name, column count, and row count of each table.

```
SELECT
      QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(name) AS table_name
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.columns AS c WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id) AS count_of_col
    , (SELECT SUM(p.rows) FROM sys.partitions AS p WHERE p.object_id = t.object_id AND p.index_id IN(0,1)) AS count_of_row
FROM sys.tables AS t
WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0
GROUP BY t.object_id, t.name
ORDER BY table_name;
```